# Checked Checkbox value in span

Tags: jquery, html

I am using a filter for a site and need those checked values to be show in a div in a span. I have gone through the article of Stack Overflow in which it is showing in a div, but  I want the value to be show in span tag. Below is the code I am using of Stack Overflow for the values.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var el = $('.dropdown_box ');
    var text= el.text();
    $('.dropdown_container').on('click', 'li', function()
    {
        var filter = [];
        $.each($('.dropdown_container').find(':checked'), function(i, el)
        {
            filter.push(el.value);
        });
        el.text(text + ('') + filter.join (''));
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dropdown_box">
    Filter Items :
</div>
<div class="dropdown_container">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="Black" class="cbx"/>Black</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="Red" class="cbx"/>Red</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="brown" class="cbx"/>brown</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="pink" class="cbx"/>pink</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="purple" class="cbx"/>purple</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="Orange" class="cbx"/>Orange</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var el = $('.dropdown_box ');
        var text= el.text();
        $('.dropdown_container').on('click', 'li', function()
        {
 var filter = [];

            $.each($('.dropdown_container').find(':checked'), function(i, el)
            {


filter.push("<span>"+el.value +"</span>");

            });

     $('.dropdown_box').html(filter);

        });
    });
```

Not checked the result try this

Comment: It is showing in a span but only one value at the time. I want to show all the checked items as it shown in a filter.
Join  the checked values

Comment: Ahhhh... Thankyou very much it works, it makes a span now it will be much easier for me to style them... Really thank you for saving my day.

Comment: Can you please help me out. The values clicked are shown in a div and when I click the values in the div it should un check the check box in the filer area.Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Define your filter array outside `.on`

**Example**

```
var filter = [];
$('.dropdown_container').on('click', 'li', function()
{
```

because every-time you `click` your `filter` array variable is re-initialize.

Comment: Sorry I did not get it.I want the selected value to be particular in span. If I click any of the checkbox the value of that checkbox should be in span so that I can style that span with particular class